# Credit Valuation Adjustment Implementation

Tags: simulations, cva

I am trying to help a friend with her thesis on Counterparty Credit Risk where she intends to have a somewhat lengthy treatment on Credit Valuation Adjustment (CVA). Specifically I am looking to help her in including some computer simulated experiments which would hopefully illustrate CVA calculations under simulated scenarios.

I have been reading a bit on CVA and have got somewhat fair idea of what's going on. However, I am at a loss to find a document where the "Math" has been distilled and computational aspects highlighted, preferably from a programmer's point of view. I have come across a [document](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/fininst/counterparty-credit-risk-and-cva.html), which is part of MATLAB's financial toolbox and it does give me some ideas.

I am looking for suggestions/pointers regarding the same.

PS: I am not averse to understanding the Math, just quite perplexed about the "only Math" aspect.

Answer (score 1):

There are good examples and spreadsheet solutions in John Gregory (2015). The maths is not complex. Computational aspects are step increments in time and simulation. Math will indicate computation ... ! A matter that requires more imagination is computational simulation on a portfolio basis (see [Credit Valuation Adjustments -- computation issues](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/815/credit-valuation-adjustments-computation-issues?rq=1)).

Answer (score 0):

The hard part of the CVA computation stems from the default probabilities. There is a lot of literature on how to model credit events, but what was being used at global banks was in the ballpark of what was implemented by [Duffie](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/7520.html)